# 【Ios】Two SimplePing instance ping two diffrent ip，recvfrom error！

Tags: ios, sockets, ping, icmp

I'm using this SimplePing sample code by Apple: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SimplePing/Introduction/Intro.html

First SimplePing instance ping 39.x.x.x and at the same time Second SimplePing instance ping diffent ip 49.x.x.x, I found sometimes the first SimplePing instance receive the icmp packet of 49.x.x.x, and the second SimplePing instance receive the icmp packet of 39.x.x.x, why?
for example: the first SimplePing instance receive the icmp packet of 49.x.x.x

Comment: You should edit your question to show relevant code, but my initial reaction would be that something called "simpleping" doesn't include any logic to route received packets back to multiple instances. ICMP is connectionless so the code needs to logic to know that there are multiple pings active and process received packets accordingly.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks, maybe the recvfrom receive all ICMP packets, i need write the logic of dispatch ICMP packet.